# Sending emails from Oracle 12c to each user for records they have yet to complete

Tags: plsql, html-email, oracle12c

I have several users who have incomplete records in the database. Some users have multiple incomplete records. I need to send each user a standard email that adds only the titles of the records that they need to complete.

I have limited Oracle knowledge and don't know where to begin doing this. What I do know is that I need to get a query of all users with incomplete records and as I loop through each user, send an email to that user that includes a sub-query of the records that they have that is incomplete.

The result will look something like this:

> **From:** noreply@ficticious.com
>
> **To:** bob@ficticious.com
>
> **Subject:** You have Incomplete Records that need to be completed.
>
> Dear **Bob**, you have the following records that are incomplete that we need completed in order to process your request:
>
> **Record A, Record D, Record F** *(query results)*
>
> Thanks for completing these records soonest.
>
> Management

Any help leading me to the right path would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could start by looking at the [UTL_MAIL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_MAIL.html#GUID-47AE34E9-3123-4115-AC86-4FF538DBFBBB) package.

Comment: Thanks, checking it out now.

Comment: While you are at it, look at `UTL_SMTP`. The `UTL_MAIL` package uses it. You may find it easier to use one or the other depending on your mailing requirements. For either, you will need to get your permissions set correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817655/11580129